# dynanmo db filterexpression with multiple condition php

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I am unable to retrieve the item using filterExpression using logical `and` or `or` in Dyanamodb php using aws sdk. can any any one provide the code  with the correct syntax to retrieve the item satisfying both the condition.

```
$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':val1' => ['S' => '20'],
        ':val2' => ['S' => 'ajay'],

    'FilterExpression' => 'age = :val1 AND name = :val2'
]));
```

i am getting error that

> filterExpression must be a associative array

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => [
        ':val1' => ['S' => '20'],
        ':val2' => ['S' => 'ajay']],

    'FilterExpression' => 'age = :val1 AND name = :val2'
));
```

badly placed closing `]` creates

```
array(2) {
  ["TableName"]=>
  string(3) "..."
  ["ExpressionAttributeValues"]=>
  array(3) {
    [":val1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["S"]=>
      string(2) "20"
    }
    [":val2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["S"]=>
      string(4) "ajay"
    }
    ["FilterExpression"]=>
    string(28) "age = :val1 AND name = :val2"
  }
}
```

instead of required

```
array(3) {
  ["TableName"]=>
  string(3) "..."
  ["ExpressionAttributeValues"]=>
  array(2) {
    [":val1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["S"]=>
      string(2) "20"
    }
    [":val2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["S"]=>
      string(4) "ajay"
    }
  }
  ["FilterExpression"]=>
  string(28) "age = :val1 AND name = :val2"
}
```